# Running Restcomm using JBOSS 7 at Eclipse

Tags: restcomm

I want to get up my Development Environment from Restcomm source code, I have downloaded the source code, I have executed the maven scripts, I have downloaded the dependencies, and the eclipse projects have his libraries.

I have downloaded the Mobicents Tomcat release, I am binding the JBoss with the eclipse IDE.. because I see libs and conf are differents to JBoss default release.

I can start the Server in the Eclipse, I can see the log without errors

```
[0m[0m12:02:33,006 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig]         (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) Root resource classes found:
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AccountsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.ApplicationsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.UssdPushJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.LogoutEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.CallsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.CallsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.TranscriptionsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.ClientsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.NotificationsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.GatewaysJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.SmsMessagesXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersTollFreeJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.IncomingPhoneNumbersXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.SmsMessagesJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.ClientsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersTollFreeXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.UsageXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.IncomingPhoneNumbersJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.NotificationsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.TranscriptionsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.UssdPushXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.OutgoingCallerIdsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.OutgoingCallerIdsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.OutboundProxyJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersMobileXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.RecordingsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AnnouncementsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.OutboundProxyXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AccountsJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.RecordingsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.GatewaysXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AvailablePhoneNumbersMobileJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.AnnouncementsXmlEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.SupservisorJsonEndpoint
class org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.ApplicationsXmlEndpoint
[0m[0m12:02:33,012 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) No provider classes found.
[0m[0m12:02:33,117 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
[0m[0m12:02:34,549 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) Vmaos!
[0m[0m12:02:34,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "restcomm.war" (runtime-name : "restcomm.war")
[0m[0m12:02:54,702 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found restcomm-management.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called restcomm-management.war.dodeploy
[0m[0m12:02:59,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "restcomm-management.war" (runtime-name: "restcomm-management.war")
[0m[0m12:02:59,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver (version 2.3)
[0m[0m12:02:59,958 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS018210: Register web context: /restcomm-management
```

But I have some questions...

First, In the restcomm.application project I found a Class Bootstrapper, But I cannot see when that class instance is created

Second, Where I can find, or Could you share me the sequence to Restcomm project entry point from JBoss AS(I can see Sip Servlet class in the server.xml, It is necesary see the Sip Servlet code also, right?)

With that I thinking that I could make a trace to understand the project.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is no longer supported for Restcomm. It is best to move to JBOSS

Comment: Thanks @TechKid I am going to JBOSS but I believe that the question will be the same, I will try

Comment: I have updated the question to JBOSS, the problem is the same. Best Regards

Comment: I have solved with JBOSS, my mistake was that I forgot to change the JBOSS Profile, I have changed standalone to standalone-sip